# How do I know if iphone system has powered on?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any mechanism available in ios to get a notification or event of iphone is switch on (ios system has finished booting) like "ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" intent available in android?

I want to start my application on phone boot up (iphone is switched on) if some flags for auto start functionality is on in my application.

Is it possible ? Can we receive notification of iphone is switch on i.e. system has finished booting in ios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately iOS doesn't support any such broadcast receivers as in Android. Atleast upto iOS 6.